# Quadratic equation problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, word-problem

Nino sells on average three cell phones more than Will. At the end of the day, they both receive $35.00$  together for the day's sales. The store manager finds that: If Will sold at price W the number of cell phones Nino sold, he would receive $24.00$. Nino would receive $12.50$ if he sold at price N the quantity Will sold. At the end of the day, the guys got together and discovered that the equation that calculates the number of cell phones sold by each one is: (Answer:$x^2-20x+75=0$)

I try
$n = w+3\\
nN+wW = 35(I)\\
nW = 24(II) \\
wN=12,5(III)\\
nN+wW=35 \implies (w+3)N+(n-3)W = 35\\
wN+3N+nW-3W = 35 \implies 12,5+3(N-W)+24=35\\
\therefore \boxed{W-N =0,5}$

but I can't finish.

Comment: I think it confuses matters to keep track of both $n,w$.  Letting $m$ be the number that Will sold (switching to $m$ to avoid confusion with $N,W$), we have $W\times (m+3)=24$ and $N\times m=12.5$ where at least you know that $m$ is an integer.  That integrality has to be critical...else you just have two equations with three unknowns.

Comment: I don't understand the conditions on price.  The bits about $N,W$ seem to be hypothetical...do we have any information on the *actual* sale prices?  If you wanted to assume that $N,W$ were the actual prices, I think you should make that clearer.

Comment: In any case, using $N,W$ as the actual prices, you can now eliminate one of them from the system.  That will get you two equations in two unknowns.

Comment: Answer: $x^2-20x+75=0 $

Comment: So, both integers.  Can't distinguish them that way.  So maybe the solution just isn't unique.

Comment: @lulu  The problem is faithfully transcribed the question

Comment: Ok, but maybe the answer isn't unique.   I agree with you that those three equations have [two solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+w*%28x%2B3%29%3D24%2C+n*x%3D12.5%2C+n*%28x%2B3%29%2Bw*x%3D35) and I don't see any way to rule one out (the numbers sold are integers, and the prices are both positive).

Comment: @lulu  I already posted the answer provided by the question

Comment: Yes....and that quadratic has two roots, both of which are physically possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141732/discussion-between-peta-arantes-and-lulu).

Comment: There's really nothing to chat about.  The system of equations has two solutions, namely the two roots of that quadratic.  That is, $x\in \{5,15\}$.  Both are physically possible, as far as I can tell.  I don't see any problems or contradictions here.

Comment: @lulu  I posted the solution of a colleague who solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the (average) number of cell phones sold each day by Will, and $B$ the average number of cell phones sold each day by Nino. They tell you that $B=A+3$, and let $W$ and $N$ be the sale price of each cell phone owned by Will and Nino respectively

Then they also tell you that $W⋅A+N⋅B=35$, $W⋅B=24$, and that $N⋅A=12.5$. You are asked to find the value of $A$ (or that of $B$). From the above you have to:

$WA+NB=WA+N(A+3)=(W+N)A+3N=35,N=\frac{12,5}{A},W=\frac{24}{A+3}$
Now substituting in the first equation the value of $N$ and $W$ is left

$[\frac{12,5(A+3)+24A}{A(3+A)}].A+(\frac{3⋅12,5}{A})=35⟺12,5(A+3)A+24A^2+(3+A)3⋅12,5=35A(3+A)⟺24A^2+(3+A)37,5=22,5A(3+A)⟺1,5A^2−30A+112,5=0⟺3A^2−60A+225=0⟺A^2−20A+75=0$

(Solution by Masacroso)

Answer (score 1):

Your result $ \ W - N \ = \ 0.5  \ $ *is* useful, but your choice of labeling for the numbers of phones sold complicated matters.  The "reference" is the number of phones $ \ x \ $ that Will sold: Nino then sold $ \ x + 3 \ $ phones.  Your equations (II) and (III) would then be $ \ W \ = \ \frac{24}{x + 3} \ $ and $ \ N \ = \ \frac{12.5}{x} \ \ . \ $  From all this, we have
$$ \frac{24}{x + 3} \ - \ \frac{12.5}{x} \ \ = \ \ 0.5 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 24·x \ - \ 12.5·(x+3) \ \ = \ \ 0.5·x·(x+3)  $$
[after multiplying the equation through by $ \ x·(x + 3) \ \ ] $
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ (24 \ - \ 12.5)·x \ - \ 37.5 \ \ = \ \ 0.5·x^2 \ + \ 1.5·x $$
[re-arranging terms and multiplying through by $ \ 2 \ \ ] $
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2 \ + \ 2·(1.5 \ - \ 24 \ + \ 12.5)·x \ + \ 2·37.5 \ \ = \ \ 0 $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2 \ - \ 20·x \ + \ 75 \ \ = \ \ (x \ - \ 5)·(x \ - \ 15) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$

So your approach does work, but you needed to settle on a single variable as a "reference" for how many phones each person sold.

The solutions are then

•  Will sold $ \ 5 \ $ at $ \ \frac{24}{8} \ = \ 3 \ $ (currency units) each and Nino sold $ \ 8 \ $ at $ \ \frac{12.5}{5} \ = \ 2.5 \ $ each (the prices differing by $ \frac12 \ ) \ \ , \ $ bringing in a total of $ \ 15 \ + \ 20 \ = \ 35 \ \ ; $ or

•  Will sold $ \ 15 \ $ at $ \ \frac{24}{18} \ = \ \frac43 \ $ each and Nino sold $ \ 18 \ $ at $ \ \frac{12.5}{15} \ = \ \frac56 \ $ each (the prices again differ by $ \ \frac36 \ = \ \frac12 \ ) \ , \ $ for a total of $ \ \frac{60}{3} \ + \ \frac{90}{6} \ = \ 20 + 15 \ = \ 35 \ \ . $